# Constantly getting TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'm getting these TabErrors constantly and it's really slowing down my work flow.  I can't figure out how to make them go away.  I get them to disappear by completely retyping my script, and then I add a new function and suddenly everything is messed up again.  I have not changed the way I indent my code.  I am not adding extra whitespace.  I am not doing anything differently but suddenly I'm getting TabErrors all the time.  I'm using vscode.  Is there something I can use to properly format my code?  I really need this problem to stop happening.

[image]

Comment: Thank you.  I didn't realize you can't mix spaces and tabs,  That's kind of a bad rule.

Comment: why? tabs are ambiguous width. how should python know what you mean, if you have one line with four spaces and the next with one tab? it would have a radically different meaning if you intended the tab to be equivalent 2, 4, or 8 spaces, all of which are valid interpretations and valid syntax depending on the context. whitespace is important in python, and thus so is whitespace consistency.

Comment: @Mike - the problem is that there is no standard width of a tab. Nominally, its 8 spaces, but it was common to reduce that to 4 spaces for python. Python wants the code to align visually. If you mix tab and space indents, python has to start making guesses about how far that tab indents relative to spaces. That is going to end in tears. Hence the error. And pythonically, we all ditched tabs a long time ago.

Comment: What do you mean we all ditched tabs long ago?  What should I be doing?  4 spaces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your `settings.json` file

```
"[python]": {
    "editor.insertSpaces": true, // if you want to use spaces, false for tabs
    "editor.tabSize": 4,
}  // you may need a trailing comma here - you've been warned!
```